# Installed Java 14 but Java -version still showing old Java

Tags: java, java-14

I have installed java 14 in my system at following location.`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1` but on running `java -version` it is still pointing to `java version "1.8.0_251"`. How do I change that to point to Java 14.

I have set my `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin` and appended the same to `Path` of system variables but still it is showing the older version.

Why is it happening, a little help will be deeply appreciated. Thanks

Comment: After changing, did you try opening a new CMD prompt window?

Comment: check this for more: https://support.inductiveautomation.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/87/0/running-multiple-versions-of-java-on-the-same-windows-machine

Comment: After changing JAVA_HOME go to path and add `%JAVA_HOME%`\bin` in windows. Open a new command prompt and check.

Comment: You need to **prepend** the path not **append**. Even better: Replace the old path with the new one. All this has to happen in the `%PATH%` variable. You need to start a new CMD after saving the changes ofc.

Comment: If you ever doubt what your title reads, try executing `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\java --version`

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, the `Path` system variable had entries from previously installed java versions. removing them did the trick. Thanks all for helping out with comments.