# Set Environment variables to Java 11 directory, but CLI -> Java -version is still 1.8?

Tags: java

I have restarted my cmd line after setting the environment variables. Javac is set to version 11, but java is still set to 8?

[image: Java -version in CLI]

I have set my path variables like this:

[image: my path variables]

There are no entries from other java versions in my Path  variables like in this question:
[Installed Java 14 but Java -version still showing old Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61722180/installed-java-14-but-java-version-still-showing-old-java)

I have double checked that java.exe and javac.exe are in fact at location C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.7\bin:

[image: my Java 11 Folder]

I have read the other questions to this problem on Stackoverflow, but it was always that they set a wrong path, forgot to append /bin or had old paths to other java versions in their environment variables. I also tried reinstalling Java 11 and restarting the computer (as last idea). What else could I try?

Comment: run on cmd: 'where java' (without ' ')
this should give u path of java executable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be caused by multiple different reasons.

Try 'where java' and 'where javac' to see where they point to. You should thenbe able to find the exact path from where java and javac are being called in your environment.

Also ensure that you only have one jdk/jre in your Path. You can try to move %JAVA_HOME% to be the first element in the Path list.

Comment: I didn't know `where Java` yet. The path was still set to the folder with version 1.8 somehow (teh system variables where correct though, and moving it up didn't change anything for me). So I just deinstalled Java SDK 8 and 11 and reinstalled 11 and now it works ;)

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention trying to uninstall/reinstall. That usually fixes the issue if all else fails

Answer (score 3):

Move `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the top and then check `java -version` in a new cmd window. Make sure you do it in both, `User variables` as well `System variables`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61644958/javac-version-and-java-version-show-different-on-command-line/61645189#61645189) to learn more about a similar problem and its solution.

Comment: I am interested about moving '%JAVA_HOME%\bin' to the top. How can this help? Is the order of the variables meaningful ?

Comment: @f.trajkovski - The values are evaluated from top to bottom in the list. If `java.exe` of the older version will be in one of the values (e.g. `C:\Windows\System32`) above your value, the system will return from there and your value will not be read. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Answer (score 1):

You can also put in your system variables:

- Click on Path
- Edit
- Click on New
- Add the whole path something like: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk11.0_172\bin (this should be your path where the jdk is installed).

This will work and you will have java 11.

Comment: Only if the author has that exact version of Java installed

Comment: @JamesB yes he will need to copy it's own path. But in his scenario I think he still have the java 8 version that is making conflicts. He might need to check the system variable if something is in there.

Answer (score 0):

I made 2 changes in order to reflect java -version as Java11

1. Control Panel --> Edit environment variables for ur account
   -->System Variables --> Path
2. Make sure %JAVAHOME%\bin should be on 1st place
3. Make sure C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath should be on 2nd place.